# Saved search in Netsuite show manufacturing task run time on completion

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a transaction saved search in Netsuite on work order completions. I'd like to show the labor run time field from the completion. Currently my search criteria has a field for "type" of work order completion and my fields has a "manufacturing operations task: run time" but it is blank. My results show the WO completions, so I know I'm pulling records, but I can't figure out why this field is blank. Any hints or advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just got the info by doing a saved search, type is Manufacturing Operation Task.